# What does the $\|^2_F$ represent in the notation $\operatorname{argmin}\left\|\text{some expression}\right\|_F^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation, matrix-norms

What does the $\|^2_F$ represent in the notation below
$$\operatorname{argmin}\left\|\text{some expression}\right\|_F^2$$

I understand that $\operatorname{argmin}$ is the min of this expression. Generally the Frobenius Norm is notated by underscore F and the L2 norm by a two. But unsure what these expressions mean combined.

Thanks so much

Comment: It probably means the _square_ of the frobenius norm, but we can't be 100% sure without knowing where you found this

Comment: Caution:  argmin is not the minimum but the value of the variable giving the minimum !